# Django: model question

Tags: python, django, models

Hello I want to make a change to my models.py.

I have two tables. Client and Note. What I want to do is have a note field in the clients table which should have some one-one relationship with the Note table.

However,the note will have to store some user, client and a date time. So I need another table to do this. But I want some one-one relationship with client and note.

A client should only be able to store in one note. A note has a user, datetime, a note text field and client (If I have a note field in the Client's table, I don't think I need this entry).

**models.py**

```
   class Client(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
        telephone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        website = models.URLField(verify_exists = False)
        fax = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
        email = models.EmailField()
        is_active = models.BooleanField()
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    class Note(models.Model):
        client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
        datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
        user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
        note = models.TextField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justinas is right. You should add a note field to your Client model, which makes the FK on your Note model obsolete. Something like this should get you started:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    website = models.URLField(verify_exists = False)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    note = models.OneToOneField(Note)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for thanks. One more question  In mysql, if you want add `note = models.OneToOneField(Note)` entry in mysql, how do I create a one-to-one field using the `alter table` command?

Comment: You should use `syncdb` or `South` for that. Don't fiddle around with the tables yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get the question, but I guess you need the [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)

Comment: I want an note entry in the Client table that can correspond to the Note table.

Comment: @Shehzad009: Please **update** the question with additional information.